# Filter timestamp from MySql by its date part

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

In MySql db I have a field of type `timestamp`. On UI I have a datepicker and I want to be able to filter data from the db by **date** only, that is, without time. Now I'm doing it like this:

```
#nodejs server

var dt = new Date("my date in str").toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace("T", " ");

var sql = "select .....
  where date(column_date1) = date('$dt')"......
```

And got wrong results. Is there any error in my code? Or, perhaps, it's due to the time-zones?

Comment: First, `dt` in your `sql` variable is not evaluated. Your sending `'$dt'` string, not its value. Try something like `date("+ dt +")`. Can't guarantee MySQL syntax nor `dt`'s value is whats expected.

Comment: @mr-wildcard, it's evaluated.

Comment: I see a simple string in your `sql` variable, not a concatenation of string + `dt`'s value.

Comment: @mr-wildcard, that doesn't matter.

Comment: Well yes it does. See @1000111's answer + this post on how to use javascript date with MySQL : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044052/storing-javascript-date-in-mysql

Comment: @mr-wildcard, what do you want? I just told you that it's evaluated.

Comment: I want to help you. Can you copy/paste parsed queries from MySQL ?

Comment: @mr-wildcard, I think it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE DATE(column_date1) = STR_TO_DATE( '"+dt+"', \"%Y-%m-%d\" )";
```

Comment: He's building a query within a Node.js script, not a native query.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood! May bad!@mr-wildcard